# maven-javadoc-plugin : How could customize the package

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

My target that's extract whole javadoc in the package com.axonivy.compensation.entity to html my maven
I already tried with:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>domain-models</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <!-- <goals> <goal>javadoc</goal> </goals> -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>com.axonivy.compensation.entity.*.java</includes>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Or following this way https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/group-configuration.html

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>domain-models</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <!-- <goals> <goal>javadoc</goal> </goals> -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>
                            <group>
                                <packages>com.axonivy.compensation.entity</packages>
                            </group>
                        </groups>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But still unsuccessfully. Now the javadoc of whole project are extracted, not just the package com.axonivy.compensation.entity,

Could anyone have some idea about that? Thanks

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it already. Use <configuration>
       <sourceFileIncludes>
        <include>**/entity/*.java</include>
       </sourceFileIncludes>
       <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
      </configuration> :) , the <include> include the package that we'd to extract javadoc